# Translate scheme to java

Tags: java, scheme, lisp, sicp, code-translation

During the reading SICP I encouraged with Exercise 2.32.

> We can represent a set as a list of distinct elements, and we can
>   represent the set of all subsets of the set as a list of lists. For
>   example, if the set is `(1 2 3 4)`, then the set of all subsets is `(()
>   (4) (3) (3 4) (2) (2 4) (2 3)  (2 3 4) (1) (1 4) (1 3) (1 3 4) (1 2)
>   (1 2 4) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4))`.  Complete the following definition of a
>   procedure that generates the set of subsets of a set and give a clear
>   explanation of why it works:
>
> ```
> (define (subsets s)
>   (if (null? s)
>       (list nil)
>       (let ((rest (subsets (cdr s))))
>         (append rest (map ⟨??⟩ rest)))))
> ```

```lisp
(define (subset s)
     (if (null? s)
         (list '())
         (let ((rest (subset (cdr s))))
             (append
                  rest (map (lambda (x) (cons (car s) x)) rest)
             )
         )))

(subset '(1 2 3 4))
1 ]=> 
;Value 15: (() (4) (3) (3 4) (2) (2 4) (2 3) (2 3 4) (1) (1 4) (1 3) (1 3 4) (1 2) (1 2 4) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4))
```

I could do it with schema, but after it I wondered: "How would I can do with java?". I thought about it because I could`t understand why it should work if we got in each recursion a sublist from the previous one.

Of course I can solute it in another way.
For instance, with this approach: all possible combinations 2^N-1, for our case this is 2^4-1

```
number binary result
1      0001    (4)
2      0010    (3)
3      0011    (3,4)
4      0100    (2)
5      0101    (2,4)
6      0110    (2,3)
7      0111    (2,3,4)
8      1000    (1)
9      1001    (1,4)
10     1010    (1,3)
11     1011    (1,3,4)
12     1100    (1,2)
13     1101    (1,2,4)
14     1110    (1,2,3)
15     1111    (1,2,3,4)
```

I rewrited a little scheme code to similarity with java one

```lisp
(define (subset s)
     (if (null? s)
         (list '())
         ((lambda (rest)
                 (append rest (map (lambda (x) (cons (car s) x)) rest))
         )(subset (cdr s)))
     )
)
(subset '(1 2 3))
1 ]=> 
;Value 19: (() (4) (3) (3 4) (2) (2 4) (2 3) (2 3 4) (1) (1 4) (1 3) (1 3 4) (1 2) (1 2 4) (1 2 3) (1 2 3 4))
```

I wrote my java implementation

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(asList(1,2,3));

        System.out.println(subset(l));
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> subset(final List<Integer> s) {
        if (s.isEmpty()) return new ArrayList<>();

        final UnaryOperator<List<List<Integer>>> f = (final List<List<Integer>> rest) -> {
            final List<List<Integer>> collect = rest.stream()
                    .map(x -> {
                        List<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>();
                        r.add(s.get(0));
                        r.addAll(x);

                        return r;
                    })
                    .collect(toList());

            rest.addAll(collect);

            return rest;
        };

        return f.apply(subset(new ArrayList<>(s.subList(1, s.size()))));
    }

}
```

In java I have the empty list (I changed Set to List in order to get by the index 0 without any tricks). And as I mentioned before I understand why my java returns the empty list, but I don`t understand how to fix my java code that it behavior matches scheme.

Comment: @azurefrog Yes, I understand it. I decided to rewrite this code from scheme to java because I noticed it and did not understand how it works in scheme. Or may be I don`t understand something in scheme code or somewhere semantics of this languages a little different?

Comment: The set of all subsets is called the power set. See it implemented [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set) in numerous languages.

Answer (score 3):

Your base case is wrong. The scheme expression `(list '())` doesn't evaluate to an empty list: it evaluates to a one-element list, whose element is the empty list. In Java, you've written `new ArrayList<>()` as the base case, which is an empty list. Instead, use something like `Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>())`.

Comment: Replacing the OP's return statement with `return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>()));` made the program work for me.  Just `return Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>());` threw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.